# Variable as Array Key - Yii Dropdown Selected

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii and I have a dropdown using the following example:

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'sex',array('1'=>'men','2'=>'women'), array('options' => array('2'=>array('selected'=>true))));
```

Here I am able to choose which option is selected. If I set two as shown in the example above the selected option is women as expected.
I am not able to statically set the selected option as I need to use a variable. I have `$selectedId` which equal 2, but when doing for example:

```
array('options' => array("$selectedId"=>array('selected'=>true))));
```

or doing like this:

```
array('options' => array($selectedId=>array('selected'=>true))));
```

I am getting no errors, but the dropdown does not have the expected selected option. Is it possible to use a variable when defining an array key?

**Update**

True string:

```
CHtml::dropDownList('package','',CHtml::listData(Services::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'is_internet = 1','params'=>array())), 'id', 'name'),array('id'=>'package'))
```

Comment: Hmm. Why not set `$model->sex = 2` before this?

Comment: @topher I have put the method I am currently using in the update which takes advantage of CHtml and does not use models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it by setting the second parameter:

```
CHtml::dropDownList('package',$selectedId,CHtml::listData(Services::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'is_internet = 1','params'=>array())), 'id', 'name'),array('id'=>'package'))
```

Comment: Happens to all of us.